# JSF page does not retrieve values from back bean

Tags: ajax, validation, jsf-2

I'm doing a dynamic view according to a dropdown selection:

there's the code:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{controller.type}" >
   <p:ajax listener="#{controller.switchPanels}" update="panels" />
   <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="option 1" />
   <f:selectItem itemValue="2" itemLabel="option 2" />
</h:selectOneMenu>

<h:panelGroup layout="block" id="panels">
   <h:panelGroup layout="block" rendered="#{controller.type == '1'}" >
   <h:inputText value="#{controller.value}" >
      <f:validateRegex pattern="^[0-9a-zA-Z ]*$" />
   </h:inputText>
   </h:panelGroup>
   <h:panelGroup layout="block" rendered="#{controller.type == '2'}" >
      Panel 2
   </h:panelGroup>
</h:panelGroup>

<h:commandLink action="#{controller.go}">Go</h:commandLink>
```

The controller:

```
@ViewScoped    
@ManagedBean
public class Controller {
   String type = "1";
   String value;

   // getters and setters

   public void switchPanels(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
      this.value = "";
   }

   public void go(){
   }
   ...
}
```

Try this scenario:

- write special characters in the value field
- press Go (causes the validation message to popup)
- try changing the selection and reselect the same panel again

The result is that the field is not cleared even though I clear it in the switchPanels method

Please any explanation would be helpful

Thank you

Comment: What is the bean scope, what is the validation error message and what is the getter/setter for controller.type ?

Comment: - View Scoped
- Ithink error message is not related
- String

Comment: Tested your code and the field is cleared after validation error and selection change.

Comment: Did you try pressing the Go button and causing the validation error to appear first ??

Comment: Yes, have you recompiled and redeployed?

Comment: yes of course, I did no change in order to recompile anyway, I wonder how it works with you ??

Comment: Note that on page load the field is not visible, is that what you are experiencing?

Comment: even after making it visible .. and change the value .. pressing GO .. error popups .. change selection twice will not clear the field

Comment: Add `process="@this"` to `p:ajax`, but should not since this is the default value.

Comment: I think it will be processed anyway I need not to do this .. I need to make sure you are getting this error anyway